# How do I force C++ to use the operator `<` defined by the compiler library?

Tags: c++, string, comparison, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare strings, where the strings are composed of numerical values only.

I defined my own `operator <` to be

```
bool operator<(const string &s1, const string &s2)
{
    if(s1.size() != s2.size()) return s1.size() < s2.size();
    return s1 < s2; // I don't want this to use mine
}
```

In the last return statement, I want the `<` used to be the one defined by the C++ library. How can I force the program to do this?

Comment: Don't write an `operator <` for `std::string`.  Instead, make your own named function/functor and use that instead.

Comment: I'm not sure this operator will do what you want, even if you get your overloading issue addressed (for example, comparing "0001" to "10").

Comment: Better yet, if you are dealing with a constrained sort of string (all characters are numeric), then it's *not* a bare `std::string`. Write a class wrapping a string, and check the constraint in the c'tor. Then `operator<` isn't in conflict with anything, since it already takes `MyString` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would not recommend overloading `operator<` for standard library classes, you could achieve what you ask for by calling the standard library implementation explicitly, eg:

```
bool operator<(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    if (s1.size() != s2.size()) {
        return s1.size() < s2.size();
    }
    return std::operator<(s1, s2);
}
```

**UPDATE**: As pointed out in the comments, `std::operator<(s1, s2)` would not work in C++20. I guess using `std::less()(s1, s2)` would do the trick then, but the way it looks, and the reason why it works (different namespaces), both suggest that this is not the way to go, and creating a custom class is a better solution for your problem.

Comment: This will not work in C++20 because this operator is removed (in favor of the spaceship operator)

Comment: `std::operator<(s1, s2)` uses [`compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare). `std::less` would use `<` (so probably infinite loop)... In C++20 `std::operator<=>(s1, s2) < 0;`, or use directly compare method.

Comment: There is no infinite loop because our custom comparison operator is not visible to `std::less`. Ugly, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Others already answered the question directly. I rather suggest you to not do it ;). As mentioned in a comment: Better don't write an `operator<` for `std::string`. Its not your type.

You have different options if you want to make:

```
std::string a,b;
bool b = a < b;
```

use your custom comparison. Strings that don't compare like `std::string` aren't `std::string`s, so it would be natural to have a wrapper. Either make the wrapper own the string, or just let it keep a reference:

```
struct my_string {
     const std::string& data;
     bool operator<(const my_string& other) {
         return ...;
     }
};
```

So that you can write:

```
std::string a,b;
bool b = my_string{a} < my_string{b};
```